# reference to other param in different function

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

what is the pythonic way to refer to another param in the documentation? should I do it at all?

for example -

```
def _private_func(param1):
    """
     description of the function
    :param1: here I want to refer the documentation of 'param1' in the main function/
    """

def main_function(param1):
    """
    description of the function
    :param1: a long explanation about param1
    """
```

I'm using pycharm, so if there is a way to integrate the reference with pycharm, it can be awsome.

Answer (score 0):

In a docstring, you'll just have to copy and paste the description in both. Probably mention that it refers to the same parameter in the main() function.